# issue with spacing list items on a page

Tags: html, css, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help trying to space an unordered list of items on a page here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

I want the border with the message "Drag a page..." to be on the right side

like this: [image]

Here is the HTML: (razor)

```
<div class="admin registrationFields white-strip padded">
    <div class="well container">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>@ViewBag.Title</legend>

            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedSiteId, new {@class = "col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSiteId, new SelectList(Model.AllSites, "SiteId", "SiteName", Model.SelectedSiteId), new {@class = "form-control"})

                </div>

            </div>



            <ul class="list-group page-reordering">
                @foreach (var page in Model.Pages.Where(p => p.ParentMenuID == null))
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item margin-space-reorder" data-menuid="@page.MenuID">
                        <h4>@page.PageName</h4>
                        <ul class="list-group">

                            @foreach (var child in Model.Pages.Where(p => p.ParentMenuID == page.MenuID).OrderBy(o => o.MenuOrder))
                            {

                                <li class="list-group-item active" data-menuid="@child.MenuID">
                                    <h4>@child.PageName</h4>
                                </li>

                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
            <input id="page-order" name="page-order" type="hidden" value="">
            <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="SaveOrderPage">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

and here is the css:

```
.page-reordering .list-group-item {
    background-color: #3071a9;  
}

.margin-space-reorder {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
.page-reordering .list-group {
   min-height: 60px;
   border: 1px #fff solid;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.page-reordering .list-group:before {
    content: 'Drag a page here to create a child page of this parent.';
    color: #AEAEAE;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left: 10px;    
}

.page-reordering .list-group-item h4 {
   color: #fff;    
}
.page-reordering .list-group-item li h4 {
   padding-left: 1px;    
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to debug when you post the generated HTML source. I guess it can be solved with a "text-align: right" or a "float:right" CSS attribut. But could only be said clearly with generated code...

Comment: right, ill edit the code part now

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer: make the `.page-reordering .list-group::before` element a block element, so it can inherit the width, from the parent element, then align text to the right.

```
.page-reordering .list-group::before {
content: 'Drag a page here to create a child page of this parent.';
color: #AEAEAE;
font-size: 25px;
font-style: italic;
padding-left: 10px;
text-align: right;
width: inherit;
display: block;
}
```

Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s751u67n/)

Comment: your answer is very close.. heres a picture of what it generated http://s28.postimg.org/v55g6u0m5/right_attempt_so.png

Comment: what do you exactly need to obtain?

Comment: here is a picture of what I need http://s22.postimg.org/oe8pb6je9/what_i_want.png